# Raspbian kernel panic CCTV system

Tags: raspbian, camera

just tried to boot up my raspberry Pi, but I'm getting a kernel panic. "Not syncing: Attempted to kill unit! Exit code= 0x00007f00"

Is there a way to fix this? I was using this Pi as a cctv system. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I assume the message was "Attempted to kill **init**" rather than "unit", correct? Have you made any changes to your system recently (package installations, config file changes) that could have caused this?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed error log? or a photo of the boot screen?
With this info, I can't do anything, because that error can be caused by many things.

Thanks

Comment: There are numerous possibilities; the SD card is one. Here's a [link that describes a few of them.](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1416)